# Growing cold climate cedar in warm climate

Tags: plant-care, transplanting, cedar

I am trying to plant some trees which are usually native to colder climates into Subtropical climate, is there any possibility that if i plant these 20 trees saplings in winters they will grow to be a tree, due to some random genetic mutation, given all nutrients all provided to it?

Tree in Question is Deodar

Answer (score 1):

The key point will be that the 20 saplings are all grown from seed, and from seed selected from as wide a parent population as possible. Given those circumstances the genetic pool represented in your sapling sample will be as wide as possible given the natural variation in the species pool. To take the contrary view, say your seed was selected from 2 cones from one tree where there are only two trees to exchange pollen. All of the seeds produced will then have a genetic pattern that will be as restricted as you can find.

Given an inherently wide array of genetics in your 20 trees you may find a couple that will survive the heat. These could then go on to parent other offspring. Of course, you could apply the same thinking to breeding a banana plant that would survive in the Arctic which is clearly unreasonable; however if the seed comes bulk collected from a forest in Pakistan then this puts you back into the realm of possibility. There may already be some trees in countries with native populations of Deodar growing in the hotter limits of their range, with some of the selection already done for you.

Existing cultivars will not be much of a guide to the possibilities since they will have been selected on the basis of very different criteria.

Comment: How is heat bad for plant, as i understand more sun more water means more energy for these plants

Answer (score 0):

*Cedrus deodara* grows in temperature ranges of between -23deg - 40degC. After that upper temperature range, and the higher the temperature is over that 40degC, the less likely the trees will grow. So far as I am aware, there are no cultivars of this variety of Cedrus that will tolerate higher temperatures; whether or not some 'random genetic mutation' might occur in your trees to enable them to tolerate higher temperatures is not something anyone can predict, but it's highly unlikely. Which means you either decide not to plant them, or take a gamble on their survival. If you already have the saplings, you might as well plant them as planned and let them take their chances.